C# : httpclient post method returns StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden'
I am using the below code to call GoogleTranslate API but getting output code Status 403.
Please advise what I am missing here?
class MainClass
{
    var postData = new PostData
    {
        q = { "hi I am Tom","Hello how are you?"},
        target = "fr",
        format = "text",
        source = "",
        model="",
        key = "123455xxxx"
    };

    var client = new HttpClient();

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://translation.googleapis.com/");

    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(postData);
    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    Console.WriteLine(content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

    var response = client.PostAsync("language/translate/v2/", content).Result;
    Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
}


**Output : **
StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Vary: X-Origin
  Vary: Referer
  Vary: Origin
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Date: Fri, 23 Aug 2024 14:24:51 GMT
  Server: ESF
  Cache-Control: private
  X-XSS-Protection: 0
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
  Accept-Ranges: none
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
}

I have tried to follow this online tutorial for calling API.

Did you also follow / check against google's documentation for the Translate API? Also : dont use .Result. await that call. (though it won't solve that problem)

Did you include this Header:  "x-goog-user-project: PROJECT_NUMBER_OR_ID"  ?

See also https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v2/translate#authorization

Yes I have followed the above google document reference. I am passing all the parameters which are mentioned in query parameters.

@user1471768 I do not see anywhere that you have included any type of authentication to the Google API. I think you need to send some headers that include an API key to authenticate to google apis: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/authentication

I think you are right. Let me try that as well. I was able to directly use the url with API key and it was working. Only with post method I think need to add header details. Will go through the documentation in detail. Thank you.

Http status code 403 means the server did receive the request but refused/rejected it for some reason, usually the reason is an authentication failure.
Having said that, find out if you were given an API key or if there was any mention of user identification or authentication. Usually when consuming external API's, you will be provided with an API-key which would be used to authenticate your requests.

I already have the API key which I passed as a parameter but it is giving 403 error. It seems when I am trying to pass parameters then it is not getting recognised. Looks like some more authentication is required.

In the OP you didn't show any part about the API key, perhaps you forgot to add it or you didn't add it properly. You can still show that part in your post and mask the API key or something.

Inside the Postdata object there is a parameter named Key which I am using to store API key.  Please check the above code.

I see it now. That is a bit strange to me, I don't know of any service that takes the api-key through a request object/body. Usually they take it in the headers or url. Is it possible you can share the link to the external api so I can read on it as if to also consume it and see how we can solve this?

@user1471768 Check out this link: link Use an API key.
There is an example like this: POST https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:analyzeEntities?key=API_KEY
